# Angular2 - EXCEPTION: Route config should contain exactly one "component"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have two simple pages that I am navigating to using routing in angular2. But it looks like I am getting the following exception:

> EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterLink -> Router).
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Route config should contain exactly one "component", "loader", or "redirectTo" property.

Here are the files

**page1.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: "page1",
    template: `page 1 goes here.`
})
export class Page1Cmp{}
```

**page2.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: "page2",
    template: `page 2 goes here.`
})
export class Page2Cmp{}
```

**app.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {Page1Cmp} from './page1';
import {Page2Cmp} from './page2';

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    template: `<a [routerLink]="['Page1']">Page1</a> | <a [routerLink]="['Page2']">Page2</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: "/page1", name: "Page1", component: Page1Cmp, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: "/page2", name: "Page2", component: Page2Cmp}
])
class MyApp{}

bootstrap(MyApp, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

I re-produced the problem on [plunkr here](http://embed.plnkr.co/49LURshDhLFNuvWUWbSX/)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was quite difficult and fun...

Your problem are your imports, look at them

```
import {Page1Cmp} from './page1';
import {Page2Cmp} from './page2';
```

Do you see something wrong? No, nothing, right?

Now take a look at those files

**page1.ts**

```
export class Page2Cmp{}
```

**page2.ts**

```
export class Page1Cmp{}
```

Do you see it now? Yes! The class names doesn't correspond to the file where they are :P, so you're importing classes that doesn't exist from each file.

So you can move `Page1Cmp` to `page1.ts`, and `Page2Cmp` to `page2.ts`.

Here's your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A9lmLg9HVSpyerXYRRkK?p=preview) working.

It actually took me a minutes to see it, it was very well hidden :P